# How to search a record using a mySql unique ID / column name?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

The following code works perfectly. It gives `hotel url` of the booking ID `RRGPGM68`

```
<?PHP
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pasword","dbName");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
$booking_id_serch_text = RRGPGM68;
$searchroute = "select * from booking_tbl where booking_nmbr = '$booking_id_serch_text'";
$result = $con->query($searchroute);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo 'Hotel URL: '.$row['hotel_url'];
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

But I want to assign the `booking_id_serch_text` dynamically from a text input field. So I altered the code as follows:

```
<form action="<?php echo get_permalink();?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." required name="search_text">
    <input type="button" value="search" name="search">
</form>

<?PHP

if($_POST["search"]){
$serch_text = $_POST["search_text"]; 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pasword","dbName");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }       
$booking_id_serch_text = $serch_text;
$searchroute = "select * from booking_tbl where booking_nmbr = '$booking_id_serch_text'";
$result = $con->query($searchroute);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo 'Hotel URL: '.$row['hotel_url'];
mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
```

But the above code just does nothing.
How can I make it work?
I'll add validation after this purpose is archived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" /> buttons
```

will not submit a form - they don't do anything by default. They're generally used in conjunction with JavaScript as part of an AJAX application.

```
<input type="submit"> buttons
```

will submit the form they are in when the user clicks on them, unless you specify otherwise with JavaScript.

So use  here

Answer (score 1):

you have to use a submit button to make the form post while you press `search`

```
<input type="submit" value="search" name="search">
```

Comment: Additional note: it's not good practice to check if the submit button is in the $_POST array; browsers are not required to send it in unless it's actually been clicked. Some browsers omit it if you press "enter" inside a text-field and then your code would not work.

Comment: thanks for that. That works like a charm.
so for second note do I have to use isset?

Comment: @RiffazStarr : I think `if (isset($_POST['search'])) {` is just fine

Comment: @Erik : thats a new learning for me. would you provide some refernces for a such a behavior. Actually I searched and couldn't find an article which states so.

Comment: I searched for articles, but cannot find any. However, you can see the behaviour easily enough if you make a simple form with a text and a submit, type something in the text, hit enter, and then var_dump the returned $_POST.
In a quick test, the submit button is posted both by Firefox and Chrome, but IE9 omits it (which means the above code will not work in IE9)

Answer (score 1):

You are not submitting the form

```
<input type="button" value="search" name="search">
```

should be

```
<input type="submit" value="search" name="search">
```